# MySQL Workbench: how to display warnings?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

When I run a particular query, I get a message: "Your query produced 1 warnings." I'd like to know exactly what the warning was about. How do I view the warning's details? I'm on Windows using Workbench version 7.

Answer (score 2):

Do you see the Action Output pane in the lower part of the SQL IDE? All queries that you send appear there and any warning or error message will too. In the toolbar at the top, in the far right corner there are 3 buttons to switch specific parts of Worbench. The middle one is for the output area. See that this is activated to have the pane actually on screen.

Comment: And when there are 50+ warning messages - how do you actually read them? A subset of them display temporarily when you place your cursor on that line a the bottom.

Comment: Uhm, have you tried to scroll the list? It's a tabular display of the return message when running queries. You can make the response column bigger to read longer messages and if they are really long copy it to somewhere for easier consumption. What else would you expect there (under the consideration that this it doesn't consume too much screen estate)?

Answer (score 1):

```
show warnings
```

should work [for more description](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-warnings.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can go to (Help -> Show Log File) and it will display the warning message.

Answer (score 0):

These 2 solutions worked for me on Workbench 6.0 on Linux, maybe one of them will work for you:

- Hover over the warning message with your mouse. Or hover over the previous message (if there are any previous messages)
- Otherwise, in the same query tab, write any other query and execute it. For some reason, the old warning message expands once I do that. It seems there's a bug with the last message in the list.

Answer (score -1):

checkout this link. It will tell you about the workbench windows.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-sql-editor-query-panel.html

Pl - use hide/show panel to activate different windows.