# MySQL result set returning different count on same query

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL 5.7.32-0 on ubuntu 18.04.1 and have noticied some strange behaviour with this query

```
SELECT *  
FROM COMPLAINT 
WHERE DATE(CREATED_DT) < STR_TO_DATE('2021-02-23','%Y-%m-%d') 
  and COALESCE(COMPLAINT_STATUS,'') NOT IN ('COM','CLS');
```

Here **CREATED_DT** is of **DATETIME** and  **COMPLAINT_STATUS** is **VARCHAR**. Most of the time the result set returns 9 Rows but suddenly sometime 16 and 10. The results are checked in Workbench and phpmyadmin.

**Update**

After inspecting which condition is mibehaving i found that the condition and `COALESCE(COMPLAINT_STATUS,'') NOT IN ('COM','CLS')`
is the culprit but dont know whats wrong with it.

**Update 2**

I created new table and moved data to new table and deleted old and renamed new table now its working fine.

Comment: Assuming your query doesn't use something non deterministic like `RANDOM()`, then it must return the same result set, assuming the underlying data remains the same.  So, either your data or your query are changing.

Comment: The table is does not get any additional data. It is isolated from any updations that what bother me.

Comment: Adding `SHOW WARNINGS` , see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559711/mysql-workbench-how-to-display-warnings#:~:text=You%20can%20go%20to%20(Help,will%20display%20the%20warning%20message.&text=checkout%20this%20link.,you%20about%20the%20workbench%20windows.) might help to find the cause.

Comment: @Luuk No warnings reported

Comment: I think you can just use `COMPLAINT_STATUS NOT IN ('COM','CLS')`

Comment: @Atmahadli  it returns no results in that case

Comment: what about `IFNULL(COMPLAINT_STATUS,'') NOT IN ('COM','CLS')` ? I also having problem with coalesce back there, and replace it with another logic.

Comment: tried the same but not success.The problem persists in `COMPLAINT_STATUS  is null` also

Comment: maybe you have problem with char encoding https://stackoverflow.com/a/2338215/6536300

Comment: Will this problem persist when you change it to `... and NOT COMPLAINT_STATUS,'') IN ('COM','CLS');` ?

Comment: Can you share the output of this statement `SELECT complaint_status, count(*) FROM COMPLAINT GROUP BY complaint_status;` ? Just to verify that there are no spaces (or other characters) in that field?

Comment: @Luuk result updates every time i run the query

Comment: Any way i copied the table with data to another table and the results are now static. I dont know whats wrong

Comment: sounds like a [REPAIR TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/rebuilding-tables.html) was needed (for som unknown reason).

Comment: yes may be something wrong with data charset as suggested or broken data.